# Printing server output data in tkinter Text widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a Tkinter text widget and I want to capture and put a server output in it.

Project folder:

```
project
| main.py
| servers_folder
| | default_server.py
```

In my main. I'm importing `default_server.py` with `server = importlib.import_module('default_server.py')`. It has to be another file tho.

main.py code:

```
def connect(server_name):
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.grid_forget()

    def run():
        server = importlib.import_module(server_name)
        server.Server().start()

    command = Text(frame)
    command.grid(row=0, column=0)

    thread = t.Thread(target=run)
    thread.start()


Label(frame, text='Server name:').grid(row=0, column=0)
server_name = Entry(frame)
server_name.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NSEW')
Button(frame, text='Run server', command=lambda: connect(server_name.get())).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Server start function:

```
def start(self):
    print('[STARTING] Server is starting...')
    self.server.listen()
    print(f'[LISTENING] Server is listening on {self.SERVER}')
    while True:
        conn, addr = self.server.accept()
        thread = t.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
```

Server handle_client function:

```
def handle_client(self, conn, addr):
    print(f'[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.')
    print(f'[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {t.active_count() - 1}')

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_lenght = conn.recv(self.HEADER).decode(self.FORMAT)
        if msg_lenght:
            msg_lenght = int(msg_lenght)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_lenght).decode(self.FORMAT)
            if msg == self.DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f'[MESSAGE RECIEVED] FROM: {addr}; Message: {msg}')
            conn.send('Message received!'.encode(self.FORMAT))

    conn.close()
```

How can I display server output in my `tkinter` text widget?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you show your handle_client function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easily for me to see the full code, but I think you can do something similar to this:

```
def start(self, msg_callback):
    print('[STARTING] Server is starting...')
    self.msg_callback = msg_callback
    self.server.listen()
    print(f'[LISTENING] Server is listening on {self.SERVER}')
    while True:
        conn, addr = self.server.accept()
        thread = t.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()


def handle_client(self, conn, addr):
    print(f'[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.')
    print(f'[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {t.active_count() - 1}')

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_lenght = conn.recv(self.HEADER).decode(self.FORMAT)
        if msg_lenght:
            msg_lenght = int(msg_lenght)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_lenght).decode(self.FORMAT)
            self.msg_callback(msg)
            if msg == self.DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f'[MESSAGE RECIEVED] FROM: {addr}; Message: {msg}')
            conn.send('Message received!'.encode(self.FORMAT))

    conn.close()


def connect(server_name):
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.grid_forget()

    command = Text(frame)
    command.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
    def msg_callback(msg):
        command.delete('1.0', END)
        command.insert('1.0', msg)

    def run():
        server = importlib.import_module(server_name)
        server.Server().start(msg_callback)

    thread = t.Thread(target=run)
    thread.start()


Label(frame, text='Server name:').grid(row=0, column=0)
server_name = Entry(frame)
server_name.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NSEW')
Button(frame, text='Run server', command=lambda: connect(server_name.get())).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: It is not working with both `command["text"] = msg` or `command.insert("1.0", msg)`

Comment: Ok, sorry, I will try to fix it.

Comment: @BokiX I have updated the answer. Can you try with `command.delete('1.0', END)
        command.insert('1.0', msg) `

Comment: I used a simple print statement for testing and it isn't even printing anything, the function is not working. I put it like this: `print(f"Message: {msg}")`

Comment: @BokiX Can you then post the full code? It is hard to debug if I can't reproduce the error. Also, did you insert `self.msg_callback(msg)` into handle_client()?

Comment: @BokiX great! Can you accept the answer if it worked? Or, if you had to do something else, can you comment what did you have to do to make it work so that future readers can also fix it?